# Migrate rows for import into existing Database, taking care of changing ids etc

Tags: mysql, data-migration

The purpose of this is to copy some rows from one environment to another without overwriting existing rows.

Sample DB:

```
INSERT INTO `school` (school_id,name) VALUES (15,'Middle');
INSERT INTO `class` (class_id,school_id,name) VALUES (12,15,'Sample');
```

The idea is `school_id` and `class_id` are auto-increments and `class` has a Foreign Key link back to `school`.  But I want to dump **just** these rows and insert them into another database that already has a `school_id` of 15.

It might be something that could look like:

```
INSERT INTO `school` (name) VALUES ('Middle');
INSERT INTO `class` (school_id,name) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(),'Sample');
```

But that would just be for this simple example.  Imagine if I had 50 classes, 25 students in each, and a few hundred grades for each student/class combo.  You could see how the `LAST_INSERT_ID()` might not work without storing it in a series of variables.

What would be the proper tool to do this kind of operation?  Can `mysqldump` do anything this smart?

Comment: Do you want to update conflicting rows? Or just leave them be?

Comment: The goal is to import these rows without affecting the older ones.  I'm not replacing or updating, more of inserting new data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this:

- Find MAX `school_id` in the target `school` table -

  `SELECT MAX(school_id) INTO @max_school_id FROM school;`
- Change all `school_id` values in source tables (`school`, `class`) - add MAX `school_id` from the previous point -

  `UPDATE school SET school_id = school_id + @max_school_id + 1;`

It might be very usefull to add `ON UPDATE CASCADE` action to the foreign key, it will help to change `school_id` in the child table automatically, e.g. -

```
ALTER TABLE class
  DROP FOREIGN KEY FK_name;
ALTER TABLE class
  ADD CONSTRAINT FK_name FOREIGN KEY (school_id)
    REFERENCES school(school_id) ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

- Make dump and import.

---

**Explanation and example:**

***Create source tables:***

```
CREATE TABLE school(
  school_id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name VARCHAR(20)
);

INSERT INTO school (school_id, name) VALUES
  (1, 'Middle1'),
  (2, 'Middle2'),
  (3, 'Middle3'),
  (15, 'Middle');

CREATE TABLE class(
  class_id INT(11) NOT NULL,
  school_id INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  name VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (class_id),
  CONSTRAINT FK_class_school_school_id FOREIGN KEY (school_id)
  REFERENCES school (school_id) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE
)
ENGINE = INNODB;

INSERT INTO class (class_id, school_id, name) VALUES (11, 1, 'Sample1');
INSERT INTO class (class_id, school_id, name) VALUES (12, 15, 'Sample');
```

***Create target tables:***

```
CREATE TABLE school(
  school_id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name VARCHAR(20)
);

INSERT INTO school (school_id, name) VALUES
  (1, 'Top'),
  (2, 'Middle'),
  (3, 'Bottom'),
  (15, 'Top');

CREATE TABLE class(
  class_id INT(11) NOT NULL,
  school_id INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  name VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (class_id),
  CONSTRAINT FK_class_school_school_id FOREIGN KEY (school_id)
  REFERENCES school (school_id) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE
)
ENGINE = INNODB;

INSERT INTO class (class_id, school_id, name) VALUES (10, 2, 'Sample2');
INSERT INTO class (class_id, school_id, name) VALUES (12, 15, 'Sample');
```

**Update source tables, increment id values:**
We should update all unique values, in our case we have to update `class_id` in the `class` table and `school_id` in the `school` table.

***Find max `class_id` for the TARGET `class` table***

```
SELECT MAX(class_id) + 1000 FROM class; -- This will return => 1012
```

***Increment all SOURCE `class_id` values `class_id + 1012`***

```
UPDATE class SET class_id = class_id + 1012;
```

***Find max `school_id` for the TARGET `school` table***

```
SELECT max(school_id) + 1000 FROM school; -- This will return =>1015
```

***Increment all SOURCE `school_id` values `school_id + 1015`***

```
UPDATE school SET school_id = school_id + 1015;
```

**That is all. We can dump source tables:**

```
INSERT INTO school VALUES
  (1016, 'Middle1'),
  (1017, 'Middle2'),
  (1018, 'Middle3'),
  (1030, 'Middle');

INSERT INTO class VALUES
  (1023, 1016, 'Sample1'),
  (1024, 1030, 'Sample');
```

**Now we can easily run this script against the target database.**

Comment: Interesting idea.  This is assuming the target table's max id is > source table id.  Also, would need some serious locking done on the target table(s) while this is going on.  And this wouldn't be ideal if I needed to insert >1 schools.

Comment: The major idea is that source and target `id` must be DIFFERENT - this is what you should do first; then just dump source data and insert new records at once without problems.

Comment: You could increment +1000 or more (not +1), then source school_id will be 1005.

Comment: And ruin the auto-increment of the target tables?

Comment: These values should not intersect. Find MAX(school_id) in the target table, add +1000 (or more), and increment source `school_id` as [source]`school_id` = MAX([target]`school_id`) + 1000.

Comment: Not saying they are going to intersect.  But if my target table auto_increment is 50, it will now be 1050.  Next time I run it, it will be 2050.  Basically stretching my auto_increment each time.  Not saying it's the worst thing.  Just not something ideal.

Comment: There won't be gaps like 1050-2050. I have added an example in my answer. I'm not saying that this is an ideal way, but I have not seen any tool that can do it automatically, so you should do it manually.

Comment: You need not even update the original tables, as the `+@max_school_id` expression could be included in the respective `LOAD DATA` commands - this would reduce the amount of time during which a `LOCK` would need to be held on the target tables.

Comment: @eggyal Yes, this also can be done using LOAD DATA. Table by table, id by id... ;-)

Comment: @Devart Thanks for all the details. :)

Answer (score 2):

Do you need to do this in SQL? Even the most basic of ETL tools would be better suited. Try pentaho or talend instead.

Comment: Absolutely right!  Not realistic to try to do this in SQL. This is exactly what ETL tools are built for.

Comment: Can any of these tools do this via cmd-line?  This needs to be done programmatically via a process.  So any GUI interfaces can't be used.

Comment: You use the interface to set up the job, and then the command line to schedule and run them - that's the usual use pattern. For example, with [kitchen](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Kitchen+User+Documentation) you can run kettle jobs.

Comment: Do you have any examples that do what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need a pure SQL solution you can very easily create a script that reads from the old database and writes to the new. I'm thinking PHP, Python, Ruby, Perl, ...

Here is a simple solution in PHP assuming you are using mysql and moving data between databases (**untested, may contain errors**):

```
$dbh1 = new PDO("mysql:host=db1.host;dbname=db1", "user1", "pass1");
$dbh2 = new PDO("mysql:host=db2.host;dbname=db2", "user2", "pass2");

$sth1 = $dbh1->query("
    SELECT
        school.school_id as school_id,
        school.name as school_name, 
        class.name as class_name
    FROM school
    JOIN class ON (school.school_id = class.school_id)
");

$sth3 = $dbh2->prepare("INSERT INTO school (name) VALUES (:name)");
$sth4 = $dbh2->prepare("INSERT INTO class (school_id, name) VALUES (:school_id, :name)");

$schools = array();

// get schools and classes
while ($school = $sth1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $school_id = $school['school_id'];
    $school_name = $school['school_name'];

    $schools[$school_id]['school_name'] = $school_name;

    $schools[$school_id]['classes'][] = array(
        'class_name' => $school['class_name']
    );
}

// insert schools and classes
foreach ($schools as $school_id => $school) {
    // insert school
    $sth3->bindParam(':name', $school['school_name'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $sth3->execute();

    $new_school_id = $dbh2->lastInsertId();

    // a loop for classes
    foreach ($school['classes'] as $class) {
        // insert class
        $sth4->bindParam(':school_id', $new_school_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $sth4->bindParam(':name', $class['class_name'], PDO::PARAM_STR);

        $sth4->execute();
    }

    // a loop for another joined table
    /*
    foreach ($school['joined'] as $join) {
        // insert join
        $sth4->bindParam(':school_id', $new_school_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $sth4->bindParam(':name', $join['join_name'], PDO::PARAM_STR);

        $sth4->execute();
    }
    */
}
```

Comment: Great idea.  I would be willing to look at scripts.  But the problem is, I'm not only dealing with class and school.  Imagine if I had more tables with unique IDs (student, grade, schedule, etc) that need to be linked.  That would be 10+ while loops deep.  Can you redesign the structure around that?

Comment: @St.JohnJohnson I have updated my code example, hope this gets you on the right track

Answer (score 0):

If you have temporary table privileges you could do:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_school LIKE school;
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'school.dat' INTO TABLE tmp_school;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_class LIKE class;
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'class.dat' INTO TABLE tmp_class;
INSERT INTO school (name) SELECT name FROM tmp_school;
INSERT INTO class (school_id,name) 
  SELECT school.school_id, class.name FROM school school JOIN tmp_school new
USING(name) JOIN tmp_class class ON new.school_id = class.school_id
```

I think this is right but it needs a bit of checking.

Answer (score 0):

One really simple trick would be to just multiply the id's with -1. Negative id is as good as any id, and I assume that your auto_increment columns start with positive numbers anyways.

Export from one environment:

```
select -1*school_id, name from school into outfile 'school.out';
select -1*class_id, -1*school_id, name from class into outfile 'class.out';
```

Import into second:

```
load data infile 'school.out' into table school;
load data infile 'class.out' into table class;
```

Obviously this is not a generic solution to your problem, but how often do you need one? :)

Generic solution would be to use write the migration logic yourself, either in ETL tool or just as a standalone script, as others have stated. And make that tool/script to use INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES and INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS to dynamically find out the tables and columns that need to be adjusted.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to eliminate the ids from the transfer. **assuming** that the school names are unique, this seemed to work on deviant's schema, and for simplicity, having the two databases on the same server:

Copy the data into a table on the new database with no ids, just names:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp AS SELECT s.name as school_name, c.name as class_name
FROM test.school s JOIN test.class c USING(school_id);
```

Add the new schools to the school table:

```
INSERT INTO school (name) SELECT DISTINCT school_name FROM tmp
LEFT JOIN school ON school_name = name WHERE name IS NULL;
```

Add the new classes (for both existing and new schools) to the class table:

```
INSERT INTO class (name, school_id) SELECT class_name, school_id
FROM tmp t JOIN school s ON s.name = t.school_name;
```

What semantics do you want if there are classes in the target databases for schools in the source that don't have that class? This is a union, if you want delete you will have to change it.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using this command in php, then there is a simple function which will give you the last id of your insert query. i.e. mysql_insert_id().

code may be like this :

```
<?php
    $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `school` (school_id,name) VALUES (15,'Middle')");
    $last_id = mysql_insert_id();
    INSERT INTO `class` (class_id,school_id,name) VALUES ('$last_id','Sample');
?>
```

if you are using in some other language I don't know what has to be done.